# How do I arrange received and send chat conversation data from JSON file?

Tags: jquery, html, json, chat

How do I fetch chat conversation data from JSON file and arrange those data in proper way to particular user.
Like in any chat application or website... I want to arrange sent and received conversation in order...

For more info here I have created a Illustration:
[image: Chat Forum]
and
This is how I was able to access it right now:

[image: Problem]

Part of HTML where I'm accessing JSON using Jquery :

```
let chatRcd1 = obj.data['chat1'];
for(let i=0, len=chatRcd1.length; i<len; i++){
    if(chatRcd1[i].from.type == "user1")
    $("<p><span>" + chatRcd1[i].msg.message + "</span></p><br>").appendTo(".recieved1");
}

let chatSnt1 = obj.data['chat1'];
for(let i=0, len=chatSnt1.length; i<len; i++){
    if(chatSnt1[i].from.type == "user2")
    $("<p><span>" + chatSnt1[i].msg.message + "</span></p><br>").appendTo(".sent1");

    let chatRcd = obj.data['chat2'];
    for(let i=0, len=chatRcd.length; i<len; i++){
        if(chatRcd[i].from.type == "user1")
        $("<p><span>" + chatRcd[i].msg.message + "</span></p><br>").appendTo(".recieved2");
    }

    let chatSnt = obj.data['chat2'];
    for(let i=0, len=chatSnt.length; i<len; i++){
        if(chatSnt[i].from.type == "user2")
        $("<p><span>" + chatSnt[i].msg.message + "</span></p><br>").appendTo(".sent2");
    }
}
```

Here is JSON file data :

```
{
"data":{
    "chat1" : [  
        {  
           "from":{  
              "type":"user1"
           },
           "msg":{  
              "message": "Hello"
              }
        },
        {  
           "from":{  
               "type":"user2"
           },
           "msg":{  
              "message":"Hi"

           }
        },
        {  
           "from":{  
              "type":"user1"
           },
           "msg":{  
              "message": "What plans for today?"
              }
        },
        {  
           "from":{  
               "type":"user2"
           },
           "msg":{  
              "message":"Nothing much. How about you?"

           }
        },
        {  
           "from":{  
              "type":"user1"
           },
           "msg":{  
              "message": "Planning to go to a movie. Wanna come?"
              }
        },
        {  
           "from":{  
               "type":"user2"
           },
           "msg":{  
              "message":"Sure why not."

           }
        },
        {  
           "from":{  
              "type":"user1"
           },
           "msg":{  
              "message": "Great. see you then."
              }
        },
        {  
           "from":{  
               "type":"user2"
           },
           "msg":{  
              "message":"ya bye."

           }
        }
   ],

   "chat2" : [  
        {  
            "from":{  
                "type":"user1"
            },
            "msg":{  
                "message": "Hi"
            }
        },
        {  
            "from":{  
                "type":"user2"
            },
            "msg":{  
                "message":"Hi"
            }
        },
        {  
            "from":{  
                "type":"user1"
            },
            "msg":{  
                "message": "How can I help you?"
            }
        },
        {  
            "from":{  
                "type":"user2"
            },
            "msg":{  
                "message":"I would like to know more about your product."
            }
        },
        {  
            "from":{  
                "type":"user1"
            },
            "msg":{  
                "message": "Sure. I will send you an email with details on our product."
            }
        },
        {  
            "from":{  
                "type":"user1"
            },
            "msg":{  
                "message":"Let me know if you have any doubts."
            }
        },
        {  
            "from":{  
                "type":"user2"
            },
            "msg":{  
                "message": "Great. Thanks!"
            }
        },
        {  
            "from":{  
                "type":"user1"
            },
            "msg":{  
                "message":"Anytime."
            }
        }
    ]
}   
}
```

Comment: Will the JSON "file" be static on a server? Or are you getting that JSON from a web service? Do you understand how and where to deploy web applications?

Comment: I'd suggest using timestamps to keep an order - then just send the whole file and let the client figure out what to display how.

Comment: I'm new to web development just trying different projects to learn... and this JSON file is static... this is a demo project that I'm creating.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the html in the DOM element from scratch by stepping through the chats and *walking* through the individual chat-contributions like this

```
 var chats=[];
 for (var chat in dat.data){
  var str='';
  dat.data[chat].forEach(ch=>str+='<div class="'+ch.from.type+'">'+ch.msg.message+'</div>')
  chats.push(str)
 }
```

and then assign it to the DOM elements `innerHTML` property (chats are separated by a horizontal line `<hr>`):

```
 document.getElementById('chat').innerHTML=chats.join('<hr>');
```

Btw: I just *love* jQuery and do almost everything with it. But it turns out that this little task can be done just as well with plain "Vanilla" JavaScript!

```js
var dat={
"data":{
    "chat1" : [  
        {  
           "from":{  
              "type":"user1"
           },
           "msg":{  
              "message": "Hello"
              }
        },
        {  
           "from":{  
               "type":"user2"
           },
           "msg":{  
              "message":"Hi"

           }
        },
        {  
           "from":{  
              "type":"user1"
           },
           "msg":{  
              "message": "What plans for today?"
              }
        },
        {  
           "from":{  
               "type":"user2"
           },
           "msg":{  
              "message":"Nothing much. How about you?"

           }
        },
        {  
           "from":{  
              "type":"user1"
           },
           "msg":{  
              "message": "Planning to go to a movie. Wanna come?"
              }
        },
        {  
           "from":{  
               "type":"user2"
           },
           "msg":{  
              "message":"Sure why not."

           }
        },
        {  
           "from":{  
              "type":"user1"
           },
           "msg":{  
              "message": "Great. see you then."
              }
        },
        {  
           "from":{  
               "type":"user2"
           },
           "msg":{  
              "message":"ya bye."

           }
        }
   ],

   "chat2" : [  
        {  
            "from":{  
                "type":"user1"
            },
            "msg":{  
                "message": "Hi"
            }
        },
        {  
            "from":{  
                "type":"user2"
            },
            "msg":{  
                "message":"Hi"
            }
        },
        {  
            "from":{  
                "type":"user1"
            },
            "msg":{  
                "message": "How can I help you?"
            }
        },
        {  
            "from":{  
                "type":"user2"
            },
            "msg":{  
                "message":"I would like to know more about your product."
            }
        },
        {  
            "from":{  
                "type":"user1"
            },
            "msg":{  
                "message": "Sure. I will send you an email with details on our product."
            }
        },
        {  
            "from":{  
                "type":"user1"
            },
            "msg":{  
                "message":"Let me know if you have any doubts."
            }
        },
        {  
            "from":{  
                "type":"user2"
            },
            "msg":{  
                "message": "Great. Thanks!"
            }
        },
        {  
            "from":{  
                "type":"user1"
            },
            "msg":{  
                "message":"Anytime."
            }
        }
    ]
}   
};
 var chats=[];
 for (var chat in dat.data){
  var str='';
  dat.data[chat].forEach(ch=>str+='<div class="'+ch.from.type+'">'+ch.msg.message+'</div>')
  chats.push(str)
 }
 document.getElementById('chat').innerHTML=chats.join('<hr>');
```

```css
div {font-family: arial}
.user1 {padding:10px;background-color:#ddd;margin-right:55%; border-radius:10px}
.user2 {padding:10px;color:white;background-color:#69f;margin-left:55%; border-radius:10px}
```

```html
<div id="chat"></div>
```

Comment: Here you have copied JSON data in js... but what if I want to do it from external file ? which way is better ? Thanks for your response..

Comment: With JavaScript you will not handle an external file directly. Most likely you will receive the relevant data from an AJAX call which will probably translate the actual JSON-*string* into a JavaScript *object*, like the one I have processed in my example.